# (Node) Dynamic promises that run n-times

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic, promise

I have an array of objects containing a users info.

```
var names=[{name: 'yoda', 
            address:'123 Compton', 
            email:'yodalicious@force.com'},
            {name: 'darth vader', 
            address:'69 harlem', 
            email:'elevader@force.com'},{....}]
```

this is a list that can range from 100 to 1000 users. 
The problem is that I need to request/pull information from the web and DB about each user and create a new array containing more details about each user. this will be 3 sources. Now each pull takes anywhere from 10 ms to 1 min. 
that is where I jump to promises. ("native-promise-only"), as an example:

```
require("native-promise-only");

function getFile(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        fakeAjax(file,resolve);
    });
}
//Recursive call
function recursivePromise(originalArray, newArray){
 if(isEmpty(originalArray) ){
  store(newArray);
  display(newArray);
}
else{
  var currentItem = originalArray[0];
  var p1 = getFile(currentItem.name);
  var p2 = getFile(currentItem.address );
  var p3 = getFile(currentItem.email);

  var newDataItem={};
  p1.then(function(msg){
    //TODO check status
    newDataItem.nameinfo= msg;
    return p2;
  })

  .then(function(msg){
    //TODO check status
    newDataItem.addressinfo= msg
    return p3;
  })

  .then(function(msg){
    newDataItem.emailinfo= msg
    newArray.add(newDataItem);
    recursivePromise(originalArray.shift(), newArray)
  });
}
}
var new_array=[];
recursivePromise(names, new_array);
```

this is a rough code, I have something similar and it works! somewhat. But a bug in me tells me that i might be setting up a future failure. I am doing it recursively because the position of the item in 'names' is important. so they need to be processed in order.

Comment: What is `fruits`? Why do you `shift()` it? What is `.add()` on an array?

Comment: Do you want to run the requests serially (not starting the 2nd one until the first has finished) or do you want to run them in parallel (up to X requests at once)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues as I see them :

Coding errors :

- `fruits` comes out of nowhere; presumably `originalArray.shift()` was intended.
- `array.shift()` removes the 0th element from the array and returns the removed element, not the array.
- `originalArray` would be destroyed, which is not a good idea.
- `.add()` is not an array method, presumably `.push()` was intended.

Pattern issues :

- The `p1.then(...).then(...)` chain is a rather cumbersome way to build `newDataItem`; `Promise.all(p1, p2, p3).then(...)` would be more readable, with `newDataItem` built in a single expression.
- Recursion is not necessary; the process would be more simply coded as `...; Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(function(newArray) {...});` (that's a second use of `Promise.all()`); although the promises will settle in any order they like, `newArray` will be congruent with `originalArray`.
- `newArray` can be generated internally, without needing to pass in `[]`.

```
function process(originalArray) {
    var promises = originalArray.map(function(currentItem) {
        var p1 = getFile(currentItem.name);
        var p2 = getFile(currentItem.address);
        var p3 = getFile(currentItem.email);
        return Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(function(results) {
            return {
                nameinfo: results[0],
                addressinfo: results[1],
                emailinfo: results[2]
            };
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function(newArray) {
        display(newArray);
        return newArray;
    });
}
process(names).then(function(newArray) {
    store(newArray);
});
```

*`display(newArray)` and `store(newArray)` could both be executed internally or externally. I split them above to demonstrate the two possibilities.*

Comment: ( ﾟoﾟ)   -that looks clean. thank you. I had to come up with a solution fast and recursive was all I could come up with. you put my hack to shame.

Comment: "The Collection Kerfuffle" section **[here](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/)** should make interesting reading for you.